# Redirecting STDOUT and STDERR for all child processes that will be started by the parent process

Tags: windows, perl

In Perl (using version 5.30.0), is it possible to programmatically (i.e. within my Perl code) change some setting that would cause STDOUT and STDERR to be redirected to a text file for any child processes that my Perl process will start from that point on? The difficulty here is that I do not control the code that actually starts those child processes (if I did, this would be extremely trivial). My hope is that there exists some kind of IO flag that I can set in my Perl process that would cause all newly started child processes to redirect their STDOUT / STDERR channels to a destination of my choice (unless the system() / exec() / whatever call used to start them explicitly supplies another STDOUT / STDERR destination).

The (highly simplified) use case I need this for is the following. I have written a generic library function that performs a task specified by the caller and, among other things, stores all STDOUT / STDERR output generated by that user-provided task in a text file. The task is provided in the shape of a Perl function reference. So far I have merely managed to redirect the STDOUT / STDERR output generated by my Perl process:

```
    local *STDOUT;
    local *STDERR;

    open( STDOUT, '>', $buildLogFilePath ) or die sprintf(
        "ERROR: [%s] Failed to redirect STDOUT to \"%s\"!\n",
        $messageSubject,
        $buildLogFilePath
    );

    open ( STDERR, '>&', STDOUT ) or die sprintf(
        "ERROR: [%s] Failed to redirect STDERR to \"%s\"!\n",
        $messageSubject,
        $buildLogFilePath
    );
```

So as long as the user-provided function doesn't start any child processes, my feature works as desired, but the moment it does start a child process, that process's output will just go to the default STDOUT / STDERR channels, effectively breaking my feature.

EDIT: I ended up using the STDOUT / STDERR repointing trick described by **ikegami** below. To allow easier re-use of this trick, I wrapped the code in a little utility class that redirects STDOUT / STDERR in the constructor and then restores them to their original values in the destructor:

```
package TemporaryOutputRedirector;

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use Carp::Assert;

sub new
{
    my ( $class, $newDest ) = @_;

    open( my $savedStdout, '>&', STDOUT ) or die sprintf(
        "ERROR: Failed to save original STDOUT in process %i!\n",
        $$
    );

    open( STDOUT, '>', $newDest ) or die sprintf(
        "ERROR: Failed to redirect STDOUT to \"%s\" in process %i!\n",
        $newDest,
        $$
    );

    open( my $savedStderr, '>&', STDERR ) or die sprintf(
        "ERROR: Failed to save original STDERR in process %i!\n",
        $$
    );

    open ( STDERR, '>&', STDOUT ) or die sprintf(
        "ERROR: Failed to redirect STDERR in process %i!\n",
        $$
    );

    my %memberData = (
        'newDest'     => $newDest,
        'savedStdout' => $savedStdout,
        'savedStderr' => $savedStderr
    );

    return bless \%memberData, ref $class || $class;
}

sub DESTROY
{
    my ( $self ) = @_;

    my $savedStdout = $$self{ 'savedStdout' };
    assert( defined( $savedStdout ) );

    open( STDOUT, '>&', $savedStdout ) or warn sprintf(
        "ERROR: Failed to restore original STDOUT in process %i!\n",
        $$
    );

    my $savedStderr = $$self{ 'savedStderr' };
    assert( defined( $savedStderr ) );

    open( STDERR, '>&', $savedStderr ) or warn sprintf(
        "ERROR: Failed to restore original STDERR in process %i!\n",
        $$
    );
}

1;
```

This way, one only needs to create an instance of `TemporaryOutputRedirector`, execute the code that should have its output redirected, and then let the `TemporaryOutputRedirector` fall out of scope and have its destructor restore the original STDOUT / STDERR channels.

Comment: Remove `local *STDOUT; local *STDERR;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file handle, it uses the next available file descriptor. STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR are normally associated with fd 0, 1 and 2 respectively. If there are no other open handles in the process, the next handle created by `open` will use file descriptor 3.

If you associate fd 3 with STDOUT, many things will keep working. That's because Perl code usually deals with Perl file handles rather than file descriptors. For example, `print LIST` is effectively `print { select() } LIST`, which is the same as `print STDOUT LIST` by default. So your change mostly works within Perl.

However, when you execute a program, all that it gets are the file descriptors. It gets fd 0, 1 and 2. It might even get fd 3, but it doesn't care about that. It will output to fd 1.

---

A simple solution is to remove `local *STDOUT; local *STDERR;`.

`*STDOUT` is a glob, a structure that contains `*STDOUT{IO}`, the handle in question.

By using `local *STDOUT`, you are replacing the glob with an empty one. The original one isn't destroyed —it will be restored when the `local` goes out of scope— so the Perl file handle associated with the now-anonymous glob won't be closed, so the fd associated with that handle won't be closed, so the subsequent `open` can't reuse that fd.

If you avoid doing `local *STDOUT`, it means you are passing an open handle to `open`. `open` behaves specially in that circumstance: It will "reopen" the fd already associated with the Perl handle rather than creating a new fd.

```
$ perl -e'
   open( local *STDOUT, ">", "a" ) or die;
   open( local *STDERR, ">&", STDOUT ) or die;
   print(fileno(STDOUT), "\n");
   system("echo foo");
'
foo

$ cat a
3

$ perl -e'
   open( STDOUT, ">", "a" ) or die;
   open( STDERR, ">&", STDOUT ) or die;
   print(fileno(STDOUT), "\n");
   system("echo foo");
'

$ cat a
1
foo
```

---

If you want the redirection to be temporary. You have to play with the file descriptors.

```
$ perl -e'
   open( local *SAVED_STDOUT, ">&", STDOUT) or die;
   open( STDOUT, ">", "a" ) or die;
   print(fileno(STDOUT), "\n");
   system("echo foo");

   open( STDOUT, ">&", SAVED_STDOUT) or die;
   print(fileno(STDOUT), "\n");
   system("echo bar");
'
1
bar

$ cat a
1
foo
```

Comment: Well, I'll be ...! It works! And it was so much simpler than I feared it was going to be, too! :)

P.S. I do want the redirection to be temporary, but I took care of that by forking a child process and then initiating the output redirection in that child process. This way, I'm making sure that my original Perl process remains unaffected. :)

Comment: Ok, now I'm observing something strange. Despite my fork-a-child-strategy, the redirection seems to be permanent rather than temporary. For some reason, although I only did the redirection in forked child process, it affects the output of the parent process as well, which is now also sent to my text file.

I had been under the impression that, if I redirect STDOUT / STDERR in a Perl process this would not affect the STDOUT / STDERR channels of the parent Perl process that started this child Perl process, but what I'm observing now seems to contradict this assumption.

Comment: Ok, I think I need to re-read and fully understand your entire post rather than just blindly follow the one-liner you posted as a comment.

Comment: Removing {local *STDOUT; local *STDERR;} __plus__ the additional restore-original-stdout dance in your 2nd snippet solved that last problem, too. :-)

Comment: [It doesn't affect the parent.](https://pastebin.com/xJQBUMqD) Are you on Windows by any chance? There's no such thing as `fork` on Windows. In Perl, it's poorly emulated using threads. Since it creates a thread instead of a new process, playing with file descriptors affects the "parent". (File descriptors belong to processes, not threads.) You should not be using `fork` on Windows.

Comment: Yep, I am on Windows 10, and I did not know about that fork emulation caveat.